# check if element is in anywhere the list

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists:

```
expected = ["apple", "banana", "pear"]
actual = ["banana_yellow", "apple", "pear_green"]
```

I'm trying to assert that expected = actual. Even though the color is added at the end to some elements, it should still return true.

Things I tried:

```
for i in expected:
   assert i in actual
```

I was hoping something like this would work but it's trying to match the first element apple to banana and returns false rather than checking the entire list and returns true if there is apple anywhere in the list. I was hoping someone can help?

Edit: The lists can be different lengths.

Comment: Does `[item.split('_')[0] for item in actual]` help?

Comment: This is assuming it will always add "_" which may not be the case. I thought more about something like .startswith() ? or .any() ?

Comment: or maybe .contains()?

Comment: What do you mean "match the first element apple to banana and returns false rather than checking the entire list and returns true if there is apple anywhere in the list"? It is not doing that.

Comment: Do two lists have the same length?

Comment: Yeah so since the first element in expected is apple, it's going to try to assert to the first element of actual, which is obviously false. I'd prefer to check whether apple is anywhere in the list, regardless whether it has a prefix after or not.

Comment: No, they're different lengths.

Comment: So your question is about checking if `actual` contains strings that have prefixes provided in `expected`, right?

Comment: Not all of them will have prefixes. But yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expected = ["apple", "banana", "pear"]
actual = ["banana_yellow", "apple", "pear_green", 'orange']

for act in actual:
    if not act.startswith(tuple(expected)):
        print(act)
>>>
orange
```

If you want it to work in the opposite way,

```
expected = ["apple", "banana", "pear", 'grapes']
actual = ["banana_yellow", "apple", "pear_green", 'orange']
expected_ = set(expected)
for act in actual:
    for exp in expected:
        if act.startswith(exp):
            expected_.discard(exp)
            break
assert not(expected_), f"{expected_} are not found in actual and " + f"{set(expected)-expected_} are found in actual"
>>>
AssertionError: {'grapes'} are not found in actual and {'apple', 'pear', 'banana'} are found in actual
```

Another way,

```
expected = ["apple", "banana", "pear", 'grapes']
actual = ["banana_yellow", "apple", "pear_green", 'orange']
for exp in expected:
    assert [exp for act in actual if act.startswith(exp)], f'{exp} not found'
>>>
AssertionError: grapes not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def isequal(actual: list, expected: list) -> bool:
    actual.sort()
    expected.sort()
    if len(actual) != len(expected):
        return False
    for i, val in enumerate(expected):
        if not actual[i].startswith(val):
            return False
    return True

print(isequal(actual, expected))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a custom assertion method..

This is a bit more than you need, but also a bit more flexible.

- Order of the entries is irrelevant
- How the color is added is irrelevant (e.g. by dash, underscore, ...)

It still has the flaw that, if you have the color `orange` added to `carot` and are looking for `orange`, it would also assert sucessfully. For such cases you need to tailor the method to your actual needs. (e.g. replace the `substring in string` by `string.startwith(substring)` etc. However, this should give you a starting point:

```
def assert_matching_list_contents(expected: list, actual: list) -> None:
    if len(expected) != len(actual):
        raise AssertionError('Length of the lists does not match!')

    for expected_value in expected:
        if not any(expected_value in entry for entry in actual):
            raise AssertionError(f'Expected entry "{expected_value}" not found')

expectation = ["apple", "banana", "pear"]
current = ["banana_yellow", "apple", "pear_green"]
assert_matching_list_contents(expectation, current)
```

Comment: I like that but I was hoping for something much simpler if possible....

Comment: You can condense it a bit more, using [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) instead of my custom method. [updated].
Further compression depends on the amount / quality of error messages you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.startswith`, along with sorted lists to find it.

```
expected = ["apple", "banana", "pear"]
actual = ["banana_yellow", "apple", "pear_green"]
expected.sort() # just looking for prefixes
actual.sort()
count = 0
for i in actual:
    if i.startswith(expected[count]): # prefix matches!
        count+=1 # move to next prefix
if count != len(expected): # since it didn't find all expected
    print("Nope!")
    assert False
```

It works because it just skips extras in `actual`, but `count` gets stuck if it can't find the prefix in `actual`, leading `count` to never reach the end of `expected`.

Comment: can we iterate over both and assert True once expected is in actual ?

Comment: What do you mean? It's iterating over both: `count` is iterating over `expected`, and `i` is iterating over `actual`... Also, what's the point of asserting True? It won't do anything, since `assert` only does something when it's False. I suppose you can though...